# How not to have overlayed plots in Python (to save as an image AND as a Latex file)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm currently dealing with different plots at once and I would like to be able to save it as an image **OR** to save it as a .tex file (Latex) to be able to import it on my Latex document but when I'm using the `plt.savefig(...)` or the `tikzplotlib.save(...)` (with the appropriate environment) the result is just something with overlayed subplots.

**So I would like to be able to 'collect' the figure in the right way for everything to looks nice (no overlaying)**

I already tried to add a `tight_layout` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Here is what I've got and what I would like as well as the python code I'm running :

**Python code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tikzplotlib
from matplotlib import rc

#The variables
angle_moteur_theorique = np.array([ 0.  ,  0.77190147,  1.54380295,  2.31570442,  3.0876059 , 3.85950737,  4.63140884,  5.40331032,  6.17521179,  6.94711327, 7.71901474,  8.49091621,  9.26281769, 10.03471916, 10.80662064, 11.57852211, 12.35042358, 13.12232506, 13.89422653, 14.66612801, 15.43802948])
angle_barriere_theorique = np.array([91.07866731, 89.85870606, 86.72892154, 82.55520246, 77.7604672, 72.57406548, 67.13171026, 61.52013482, 55.79906609, 50.0130552 , 44.1985095 , 38.38846038, 32.61646301, 26.92062793, 21.34884296, 15.96679822, 10.87188966,  6.21969357,  2.27915911, -0.44028002, -0.86128366])
Temps = np.array([0.  , 0.  , 0.07, 0.14, 0.21, 0.28, 0.35, 0.42, 0.49, 0.56, 0.63, 0.7 , 0.77, 0.84, 0.91, 0.98, 1.05, 1.16, 1.23, 1.3 , 1.37, 1.44, 1.51, 1.58, 1.65, 1.72, 1.79, 1.86, 1.93, 2.  , 2.07, 2.14, 2.21, 2.28, 2.35, 2.42, 2.49, 2.56, 2.63, 2.7 , 2.77, 2.84, 2.91, 2.98, 3.05, 3.12, 3.19, 3.26, 3.33, 3.4 , 3.47, 3.54, 3.61, 3.68, 3.75, 3.82, 3.89, 3.96, 4.03, 4.1 , 4.17, 4.24, 4.31, 4.37, 4.44, 4.51, 4.58, 4.65, 4.72, 4.79, 4.86, 4.93, 5.21, 5.28, 5.35, 5.42, 5.49, 5.56, 5.63, 5.7 , 5.77, 5.84, 5.91, 5.98, 6.05, 6.12, 6.19, 6.26, 6.33, 6.4 , 6.51, 6.58, 6.65, 6.72, 6.79, 6.86, 6.93, 7.  , 7.07, 7.14, 7.21, 7.28, 7.35, 7.42, 7.49, 7.56, 7.63, 7.7 , 7.77, 7.84, 7.91, 7.98, 8.05, 8.12, 8.19, 8.26, 8.33, 8.4 , 8.47, 8.54, 8.61, 8.68, 8.75, 8.82, 8.89, 8.96, 9.03, 9.1 , 9.17, 9.24, 9.31, 9.38, 9.45, 9.52, 9.59, 9.66, 9.73, 9.8 , 9.87, 9.94])
Vitesse_moteur_corrigee = np.array([ 0.  ,  0.15,  0.65,  1.4 ,  2.2 ,  3.05,  3.9 ,  4.75,  5.65, 6.5 ,  7.4 ,  8.25,  9.1 ,  9.55,  9.75,  9.9 ,  9.95,  9.8 , 9.55,  9.25,  8.9 ,  8.6 ,  8.25,  7.9 ,  7.55,  7.2 ,  6.85, 6.5 ,  6.15,  5.8 ,  5.45,  5.1 ,  4.75,  4.4 ,  4.05,  3.7 , 3.35,  3.  ,  2.75,  2.65,  2.55,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 , 2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 , 2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 , 2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 , 1.05,  0.55,  0.05, -0.8 , -1.6 , -2.45, -3.3 , -4.15, -5.05, -5.95, -6.8 , -7.65, -8.55, -9.3 , -9.65, -9.8 , -9.9 , -9.95, -9.8 , -9.55, -9.25, -8.9 , -8.55, -8.2 , -7.9 , -7.55, -7.2 , -6.85, -6.5 , -6.15, -5.8 , -5.45, -5.1 , -4.75, -4.4 , -4.05, -3.7 , -3.35, -3.  , -2.75, -2.6 , -2.55, -2.55, -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 ])
position_angulaire_moteur = np.array([ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.046,  0.144,  0.298,  0.512,  0.785,  1.118, 1.514,  1.969,  2.487,  3.064,  3.701,  4.369,  5.052,  5.745, 6.442,  7.52 ,  8.188,  8.836,  9.459, 10.061, 10.638, 11.191, 11.72 , 12.224, 12.704, 13.159, 13.59 , 13.996, 14.378, 14.735, 15.067, 15.375, 15.659, 15.918, 16.152, 16.362, 16.554, 16.74 , 16.918, 17.093, 17.268, 17.443, 17.618, 17.793, 17.968, 18.143, 18.318, 18.493, 18.668, 18.843, 19.018, 19.193, 19.368, 19.543, 19.718, 19.893, 20.068, 20.243, 20.418, 20.593, 20.768, 20.918, 21.093, 21.268, 21.443, 21.618, 21.793, 21.968, 22.143, 22.318, 22.612, 22.65 , 22.653, 22.597, 22.485, 22.314, 22.083, 21.792, 21.439, 21.022, 20.546, 20.01 , 19.412, 18.761, 18.085, 17.399, 16.706, 16.009, 14.931, 14.262, 13.614, 12.991, 12.392, 11.818, 11.265, 10.736, 10.232,  9.753,  9.298,  8.867,  8.461,  8.079, 7.722,  7.39 ,  7.082,  6.798,  6.539,  6.304,  6.094,  5.901, 5.719,  5.541,  5.362,  5.187,  5.012,  4.837,  4.662,  4.487, 4.312,  4.137,  3.962,  3.787,  3.612,  3.437,  3.262,  3.087, 2.912,  2.737,  2.562,  2.387,  2.212,  2.037,  1.862,  1.687, 1.512,  1.337,  1.162,  0.987])
indice_premier_palier = 41
Positions = np.array([89.47, 89.35, 89.57, 89.47, 89.04, 88.41, 87.35, 85.86, 83.84,81.3 , 78.1 , 74.28, 69.62, 64.72, 59.65, 53.91, 48.61, 40.54,34.9 , 29.71, 24.29, 19.41, 15.07, 11.22,  7.72,  4.34,  1.26,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.74,3.7 ,  6.98, 10.92, 15.48, 20.68, 26.41, 32.04, 37.66, 43.29,51.57, 57.1 , 61.97, 66.75, 71.21, 75.56, 79.27, 82.9 , 85.86,88.3 , 90.09, 89.47, 88.61, 89.04, 89.78, 89.35, 89.47, 89.67,89.78, 89.67, 89.67, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.89,89.78, 89.78, 89.89, 89.89, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78,89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.89, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78,89.78, 89.89, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78])
Reg_lin = np.array([96.93466899, 91.67787419, 86.42107939, 81.16428459, 75.90748979,70.65069499, 65.39390019, 60.13710539, 54.88031058, 49.62351578,44.36672098, 39.10992618, 33.85313138, 28.59633658, 23.33954178,18.08274698, 12.82595218,  7.56915738,  2.31236258, -2.94443222,-8.20122702])
ERREUR = 5



def conclusion():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,3)

    axs[0,0].plot(angle_moteur_theorique, angle_barriere_theorique, color='#ff7f0e', label='Loi E-S théorique')
    axs[0,0].set_xlabel('Nombre de tours du moteur', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,0].set_ylabel('Angle de la barrière (°)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,0].set_yticks([10*i for i in range(0,10)])
    axs[0,0].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,16)])
    axs[0,0].grid(True)
    axs[0,0].set_title('Loi d\'entrée-sortie géométrique barrière la Sinusmatic', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,0].set_xlim(0,15.5)
    axs[0,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,0].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})


    axs[0,1].plot(Temps, Vitesse_moteur_corrigee, label='Vitesse du moteur (en tr/s)')
    axs[0,1].set_xlabel('Temps (s)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,1].set_ylabel('Vitesse de rotation \n du moteur (tr/s)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,1].set_title('Vitesse de rotation du moteur en fonction du temps', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,1].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,11)])
    axs[0,1].set_yticks([i for i in range(-10,11,2)])
    axs[0,1].set_xlim(0,10)
    axs[0,1].grid()
    axs[0,1].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,1].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,1].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})


    axs[0,2].plot(Temps, position_angulaire_moteur, label='Position angulaire moteur')
    axs[0,2].set_xlabel('Temps (s)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,2].set_ylabel('Position angulaire du moteur (Nombre de tours)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,2].set_title('Position angulaire du moteur en fonction du temps', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,2].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,11)])
    axs[0,2].set_yticks([i for i in range(0,23,2)])
    axs[0,2].set_xlim(0,10)
    axs[0,2].grid()
    axs[0,2].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,2].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,2].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})


    axs[1,0].plot(position_angulaire_moteur[:indice_premier_palier], Position[:indice_premier_palier], label='Loi E-S expérimentale')
    axs[1,0].set_xlabel('Nombre de tours du moteur', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,0].set_ylabel('Angle de la barrière (°)', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,0].set_yticks([10*i for i in range(0,10)])
    axs[1,0].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,16)])
    axs[1,0].grid(True)
    axs[1,0].set_title('Loi d\'entrée-sortie expérimentale de la barrière Sinusmatic', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,0].set_xlim(0,15.5)
    axs[1,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[1,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    axs[1,0].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})


    axs[1,1].plot(position_angulaire_moteur[:indice_premier_palier], Position[:indice_premier_palier], label='Courbe expérimentale')
    axs[1,1].plot(angle_moteur_theorique, angle_barriere_theorique, label='Courbe théorique')
    axs[1,1].set_xlabel('Nombre de tours du moteur', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,1].set_ylabel('Angle de la barrière (°)', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,1].set_yticks([10*i for i in range(0,10)])
    axs[1,1].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,16)])
    axs[1,1].grid(True)
    axs[1,1].set_title('Comparaison des lois d\'entrée-sortie\nexpérimentale et théorique de la barrière Sinusmatic', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,1].set_xlim(0,15.5)
    axs[1,1].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})
    axs[1,1].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[1,1].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')


    axs[1,2].plot(angle_moteur_theorique, angle_barriere_theorique, color='#1f77b4', label = 'Valeurs théoriques')
    axs[1,2].plot(angle_moteur_theorique, reg_lin, 'r--', label = 'Régression linéaire')
    axs[1,2].set_title('Evaluation de l\'écart entre les valeurs vraies \n et la régression linéaire', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,2].set_xlabel('Nombre de tour du moteur', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,2].set_ylabel('Angle de la barrière', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,2].text(0,0,'Erreur de ' + str(round(ERREUR,2)), fontsize='small')
    axs[1,2].legend(loc = 'best', prop={'size':6})
    axs[1,2].set_yticks([10*i for i in range(0,10)])
    axs[1,2].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,16)])
    axs[1,2].grid(True)
    axs[1,2].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[1,2].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
```

The end of the function `conclusion()` depends on what I'm doing :

**1. Saving the plots as an image :**
the end of the function is :

```
    fig.tight_layout(pad=0.1)
    plt.savefig('Bilan.png', dpi=1200, bbox_inches='tight')
```

**2. Saving the plots as a tex file :**
the end of the function is :

```
    fig.tight_layout(pad=0.1)
    tikzplotlib.save('Bilan.tex')
```

The environment for the Latex file is this one, that should be run before executing the function :

```
matplotlib.use("pgf")
matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    'font.family': 'serif',
    'text.usetex': True,
    'pgf.rcfonts': False,
})
```

To save the plots as a picture, this is the environment to use, that should be run before executing the function :

```
matplotlib.use("MacOSX")
matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    'font.family': 'serif',
    'text.usetex': True,
    'pgf.rcfonts': False,
})
```

So, here is what I would like (**the goal**):
[image: The objective]

and this is what I currently have :

**1. When saving as an image :**
[image: Image saving]

**2. When saving as a tex file :**
[image: The Latex results]

And here is the Latex code, if needed :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{figure}[ht!]
            \begin{center}
                \input{Bilan.tex}
            \end{center} 
            \caption{Bilan} 
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Latex will display pdf and png figures.  Matplotlib has a pgf backend as well.  These will all get you much closer to your desired output.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I know that latex can deal with both and that matplotlib has a pfg backend (as shown in the script above) but the thing is that wether I try one way or the other, the label axes and the titles overlayed on each other with make it very difficult to be readable

Comment: Make your figure larger, and use constrained layout https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was fiddling with your code a little and unless I am missing something a simple export to a pdf with `fig.tight_layout(pad=3.5)` and `plt.savefig('example.pdf')` seems to work all right (perhaps `tight_layout` should be a little larger). I haven't touched font size of your labels but everything else seems to look Okey.

This is what the code in `jupyter` prints out:

[image]

The code I altered exports the figure to a PDF and `\includegraphics` is what I use in LaTeX; note I wrap the figure inside `sidewaysfigure` environment in order to rotate it and utilise the whole available space. To me, this is rather a clear presentation apart from small fonts

[image]

---

The code for LaTeX

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[figure]{skip=0pt,position=bottom}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % Required only for dummy text (\kant[X][Y])
\usepackage{showframe}    % Draws frame around the page in PDF
\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1-3]

Reference to the figure~\ref{fig:six-figures}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textheight]{example}
  \caption{The six figures.}\label{fig:six-figures}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

---

The code for `jupyter notebook` (Python)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import tikzplotlib
from matplotlib import rc

#The variables
angle_moteur_theorique = np.array([ 0.  ,  0.77190147,  1.54380295,  2.31570442,  3.0876059 , 3.85950737,  4.63140884,  5.40331032,  6.17521179,  6.94711327, 7.71901474,  8.49091621,  9.26281769, 10.03471916, 10.80662064, 11.57852211, 12.35042358, 13.12232506, 13.89422653, 14.66612801, 15.43802948])
angle_barriere_theorique = np.array([91.07866731, 89.85870606, 86.72892154, 82.55520246, 77.7604672, 72.57406548, 67.13171026, 61.52013482, 55.79906609, 50.0130552 , 44.1985095 , 38.38846038, 32.61646301, 26.92062793, 21.34884296, 15.96679822, 10.87188966,  6.21969357,  2.27915911, -0.44028002, -0.86128366])
Temps = np.array([0.  , 0.  , 0.07, 0.14, 0.21, 0.28, 0.35, 0.42, 0.49, 0.56, 0.63, 0.7 , 0.77, 0.84, 0.91, 0.98, 1.05, 1.16, 1.23, 1.3 , 1.37, 1.44, 1.51, 1.58, 1.65, 1.72, 1.79, 1.86, 1.93, 2.  , 2.07, 2.14, 2.21, 2.28, 2.35, 2.42, 2.49, 2.56, 2.63, 2.7 , 2.77, 2.84, 2.91, 2.98, 3.05, 3.12, 3.19, 3.26, 3.33, 3.4 , 3.47, 3.54, 3.61, 3.68, 3.75, 3.82, 3.89, 3.96, 4.03, 4.1 , 4.17, 4.24, 4.31, 4.37, 4.44, 4.51, 4.58, 4.65, 4.72, 4.79, 4.86, 4.93, 5.21, 5.28, 5.35, 5.42, 5.49, 5.56, 5.63, 5.7 , 5.77, 5.84, 5.91, 5.98, 6.05, 6.12, 6.19, 6.26, 6.33, 6.4 , 6.51, 6.58, 6.65, 6.72, 6.79, 6.86, 6.93, 7.  , 7.07, 7.14, 7.21, 7.28, 7.35, 7.42, 7.49, 7.56, 7.63, 7.7 , 7.77, 7.84, 7.91, 7.98, 8.05, 8.12, 8.19, 8.26, 8.33, 8.4 , 8.47, 8.54, 8.61, 8.68, 8.75, 8.82, 8.89, 8.96, 9.03, 9.1 , 9.17, 9.24, 9.31, 9.38, 9.45, 9.52, 9.59, 9.66, 9.73, 9.8 , 9.87, 9.94])
Vitesse_moteur_corrigee = np.array([ 0.  ,  0.15,  0.65,  1.4 ,  2.2 ,  3.05,  3.9 ,  4.75,  5.65, 6.5 ,  7.4 ,  8.25,  9.1 ,  9.55,  9.75,  9.9 ,  9.95,  9.8 , 9.55,  9.25,  8.9 ,  8.6 ,  8.25,  7.9 ,  7.55,  7.2 ,  6.85, 6.5 ,  6.15,  5.8 ,  5.45,  5.1 ,  4.75,  4.4 ,  4.05,  3.7 , 3.35,  3.  ,  2.75,  2.65,  2.55,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 , 2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 , 2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 , 2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 , 1.05,  0.55,  0.05, -0.8 , -1.6 , -2.45, -3.3 , -4.15, -5.05, -5.95, -6.8 , -7.65, -8.55, -9.3 , -9.65, -9.8 , -9.9 , -9.95, -9.8 , -9.55, -9.25, -8.9 , -8.55, -8.2 , -7.9 , -7.55, -7.2 , -6.85, -6.5 , -6.15, -5.8 , -5.45, -5.1 , -4.75, -4.4 , -4.05, -3.7 , -3.35, -3.  , -2.75, -2.6 , -2.55, -2.55, -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 , -2.5 ])
position_angulaire_moteur = np.array([ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.046,  0.144,  0.298,  0.512,  0.785,  1.118, 1.514,  1.969,  2.487,  3.064,  3.701,  4.369,  5.052,  5.745, 6.442,  7.52 ,  8.188,  8.836,  9.459, 10.061, 10.638, 11.191, 11.72 , 12.224, 12.704, 13.159, 13.59 , 13.996, 14.378, 14.735, 15.067, 15.375, 15.659, 15.918, 16.152, 16.362, 16.554, 16.74 , 16.918, 17.093, 17.268, 17.443, 17.618, 17.793, 17.968, 18.143, 18.318, 18.493, 18.668, 18.843, 19.018, 19.193, 19.368, 19.543, 19.718, 19.893, 20.068, 20.243, 20.418, 20.593, 20.768, 20.918, 21.093, 21.268, 21.443, 21.618, 21.793, 21.968, 22.143, 22.318, 22.612, 22.65 , 22.653, 22.597, 22.485, 22.314, 22.083, 21.792, 21.439, 21.022, 20.546, 20.01 , 19.412, 18.761, 18.085, 17.399, 16.706, 16.009, 14.931, 14.262, 13.614, 12.991, 12.392, 11.818, 11.265, 10.736, 10.232,  9.753,  9.298,  8.867,  8.461,  8.079, 7.722,  7.39 ,  7.082,  6.798,  6.539,  6.304,  6.094,  5.901, 5.719,  5.541,  5.362,  5.187,  5.012,  4.837,  4.662,  4.487, 4.312,  4.137,  3.962,  3.787,  3.612,  3.437,  3.262,  3.087, 2.912,  2.737,  2.562,  2.387,  2.212,  2.037,  1.862,  1.687, 1.512,  1.337,  1.162,  0.987])
indice_premier_palier = 41
Positions = np.array([89.47, 89.35, 89.57, 89.47, 89.04, 88.41, 87.35, 85.86, 83.84,81.3 , 78.1 , 74.28, 69.62, 64.72, 59.65, 53.91, 48.61, 40.54,34.9 , 29.71, 24.29, 19.41, 15.07, 11.22,  7.72,  4.34,  1.26,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.74,3.7 ,  6.98, 10.92, 15.48, 20.68, 26.41, 32.04, 37.66, 43.29,51.57, 57.1 , 61.97, 66.75, 71.21, 75.56, 79.27, 82.9 , 85.86,88.3 , 90.09, 89.47, 88.61, 89.04, 89.78, 89.35, 89.47, 89.67,89.78, 89.67, 89.67, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.89,89.78, 89.78, 89.89, 89.89, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78,89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.89, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78,89.78, 89.89, 89.78, 89.78, 89.78])
Reg_lin = np.array([96.93466899, 91.67787419, 86.42107939, 81.16428459, 75.90748979,70.65069499, 65.39390019, 60.13710539, 54.88031058, 49.62351578,44.36672098, 39.10992618, 33.85313138, 28.59633658, 23.33954178,18.08274698, 12.82595218,  7.56915738,  2.31236258, -2.94443222,-8.20122702])
ERREUR = 5

# matplotlib.use("pgf")
# matplotlib.rcParams.update({
#     "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
#     'font.family': 'serif',
#     'text.usetex': True,
#     'pgf.rcfonts': False,
# })

def conclusion():
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(16,8))
    fig.tight_layout(pad=3.5)

    axs[0,0].plot(angle_moteur_theorique, angle_barriere_theorique, color='#ff7f0e', label='Loi E-S théorique')
    axs[0,0].set_xlabel('Nombre de tours du moteur', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,0].set_ylabel('Angle de la barrière (°)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,0].set_yticks([10*i for i in range(0,10)])
    axs[0,0].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,16)])
    axs[0,0].grid(True)
    axs[0,0].set_title('Loi d\'entrée-sortie géométrique barrière la Sinusmatic', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,0].set_xlim(0,15.5)
    axs[0,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,0].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})

    axs[0,1].plot(Temps, Vitesse_moteur_corrigee, label='Vitesse du moteur (en tr/s)')
    axs[0,1].set_xlabel('Temps (s)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,1].set_ylabel('Vitesse de rotation \n du moteur (tr/s)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,1].set_title('Vitesse de rotation du moteur en fonction du temps', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,1].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,11)])
    axs[0,1].set_yticks([i for i in range(-10,11,2)])
    axs[0,1].set_xlim(0,10)
    axs[0,1].grid()
    axs[0,1].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,1].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,1].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})

    axs[0,2].plot(Temps, position_angulaire_moteur, label='Position angulaire moteur')
    axs[0,2].set_xlabel('Temps (s)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,2].set_ylabel('Position angulaire du moteur (Nombre de tours)', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,2].set_title('Position angulaire du moteur en fonction du temps', fontsize='small')
    axs[0,2].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,11)])
    axs[0,2].set_yticks([i for i in range(0,23,2)])
    axs[0,2].set_xlim(0,10)
    axs[0,2].grid()
    axs[0,2].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,2].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    axs[0,2].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})

    axs[1,0].plot(position_angulaire_moteur[:indice_premier_palier], label='Loi E-S expérimentale')   #Position[:indice_premier_palier], 
    axs[1,0].set_xlabel('Nombre de tours du moteur', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,0].set_ylabel('Angle de la barrière (°)', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,0].set_yticks([10*i for i in range(0,10)])
    axs[1,0].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,16)])
    axs[1,0].grid(True)
    axs[1,0].set_title('Loi d\'entrée-sortie expérimentale de la barrière Sinusmatic', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,0].set_xlim(0,15.5)
    axs[1,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[1,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    axs[1,0].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})

    axs[1,1].plot(position_angulaire_moteur[:indice_premier_palier], label='Courbe expérimentale') # Position[:indice_premier_palier], 
    axs[1,1].plot(angle_moteur_theorique, angle_barriere_theorique, label='Courbe théorique')
    axs[1,1].set_xlabel('Nombre de tours du moteur', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,1].set_ylabel('Angle de la barrière (°)', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,1].set_yticks([10*i for i in range(0,10)])
    axs[1,1].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,16)])
    axs[1,1].grid(True)
    axs[1,1].set_title('Comparaison des lois d\'entrée-sortie\nexpérimentale et théorique de la barrière Sinusmatic', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,1].set_xlim(0,15.5)
    axs[1,1].legend(loc='best', prop={'size':6})
    axs[1,1].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[1,1].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')

    axs[1,2].plot(angle_moteur_theorique, angle_barriere_theorique, color='#1f77b4', label = 'Valeurs théoriques')
    axs[1,2].plot(angle_moteur_theorique, 'r--', label = 'Régression linéaire')   # reg_lin, 
    axs[1,2].set_title('Evaluation de l\'écart entre les valeurs vraies \n et la régression linéaire', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,2].set_xlabel('Nombre de tour du moteur', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,2].set_ylabel('Angle de la barrière', fontsize='small')
    axs[1,2].text(0,0,'Erreur de ' + str(round(ERREUR,2)), fontsize='small')
    axs[1,2].legend(loc = 'best', prop={'size':6})
    axs[1,2].set_yticks([10*i for i in range(0,10)])
    axs[1,2].set_xticks([i for i in range(0,16)])
    axs[1,2].grid(True)
    axs[1,2].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize='small')
    axs[1,2].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize='small')
    
    plt.savefig('example.pdf')

# New cell
conclusion()
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late answer... I've been able to overcome my issue with the ```figsize=(16,8)``` parameters in the ```put.sublots()```. I think that it is the most important thing